# What data type should I use in MySQL to store daily items and plot 1-year charts?

Tags: mysql, plot, charts

I am developing a web application and I want to plot a 1-year chart with daily data points.

The x-axis is time (date) and the y-axis is of numeric type.

- MySQL version: 8.0 (or higher)
- The [DDBB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65016/what-is-meant-by-ddbb/68323#68323) must store data points for multiple customers.
- For each customer I want to show the last 365 data points (1-year data).
- Each data point is a tuple: (date, int). For example: (2022/11/10, 35)
- The chart displays data for one single customer at a time.
- Every day a new data point is calculated and added to the customer dataset.
- Every customer must contain up to 5 years of data points
- The number of customers is 1000.

Assuming **customer** is a foreign key (FK) to the **Customers** table, I have considered two options for the *dataset*.

## Option A

| Primary Key | Customer(FK) | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Customer 1 | Date 1 | Val1 |
| 2 | Customer 1 | Date 2 | Val2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| N | Customer 1 | Date N | ValN |
| N+1 | Customer 2 | Date 1 | ValN+1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2N | Customer 2 | Date N | Val2N |

## Option B

Use a **JSON** type for the dataset

| Primary Key | Customer(FK) | Dataset |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Customer 1 | Dataset 1 |
| 2 | Customer 2 | Dataset 2 |

Where each dataset looks like:

((2022/01/01, 35), (2022/01/02, 17), ...., (2022/12/31, 42))

## Comments:

My interest is to plot the chart **as fast as possible** and since data insert/update operations  only happen once a day (for every customer), my question is:

Which option is better for data retrieval?

Right now I have around 50 customers and 2-year data history, but I don't know how the DDBB will perform when I increase both, the number of customers and years.

Additionally, I am using a JavaScript plotting library in the frontend so I was wondering whether the JSON data type approach could fit better for this purpose.

Comment: if the data is int, use the `INT` datatype. What's the problem?

Comment: Don't put multiple parts of the data in a single column. Put the date in a date column, and value in a value column.

Comment: @Barmar There is no problem at all. I am just asking which approach would be better for this scenario. Given your answer, I assume you go with option A, right?

Comment: Yes. There's rarely any good reason to put formatted data rather than the raw data in tables.

Comment: seems like (customer, date) could be the primary key instead of having a separate one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE datapoints (
    c_id  SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    date  DATE NOT NULL,
    datapoint  SMALLINT/MEDIUMINT/INT [UNSIGNED] /FLOAT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(c_id, date),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Pick the smallest datatype that is appropriate for your values.  For example, `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` takes only 2 bytes and allows non-negative values up to 64K.  FLOAT is 4 bytes and has a big range and far more significant digits (about 7) than you can reasonably graph.

The main queries.  First various ways to do the daily INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO datapoints (c_id, date, datapoint)
    VALUES(?,?,?);
or
INSERT INTO datapoints (c_id, date, datapoint)
    VALUES
        (?,?,?),
        (?,?,?), ...
        (?,?,?);   -- 1000 rows batched
or
LOAD DATA ...
```

Fetching for the graph:

```
SELECT date, datapoint
    FROM datapoints
    WHERE c_id = ...
      AND date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR   -- or whatever
    ORDER BY date;
```

1.8M rows (probably under 1GB) is not very big.  Still, I recommend the `PRIMARY KEY` be in that order and not involve an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  The INSERT(s) will poke into the table at 1000 places once a day.  The SELECT (for graphing) will find all the data clustered together -- very fast.

If you will be keeping the data past the year, we can discuss things further.  Meanwhile, to purge after 5 years, this will be slow, but it is only once a day:

```
DELETE FROM datapoints
    WHERE date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 YEAR;
```